# How to display checkbox in leaf node of dynatree?

Tags: javascript, dynatree

I have implemented dynatree with checkbox=true. but i want to display checkbox only for leaf nodes. how to achieve this ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to set `hideCheckbox: true` on nodes that are not leafs

Take a look at the example: [Example: Selection and checkbox](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/sample-select.html)